# Formatting numbers in a Grid

Tags: formatting, grid-layouts

I have a report that I currently export to Excel in order to format it nicely.  I'd like to be able to produce a reasonably well formatted report directly in Mathematica.  It looks like I can use `Grid` in order to set up the structure of the report.  However I'd like to also format the numbers.  I see that I can use `NumberForm` to handle some of the formatting, but I can't seem to then get the output from `NumberForm` to work inside Grid.  Probably because `NumberForm` "prints" the results.  Additionally I have some columns that appear in scientific notation if the number is large enough. I would like that column to have all in scientific notation or none in scientific notation.  I tried using `ExponentFunction` in `NumberForm`, but without begin able to embed `NumberForm` results in `Grid` it didn't work.  I was hoping that there might be some global setting for this threshold.

In addition to the above, I'd appreciate any suggestions about formatting a 2-dimensional table in Mathematica without having to go to Excel.

EDIT - sample:

I haven't gotten as far as headings. I'd want to align the columns.  Colums 2 & 4 should probably stay in scientific notation for all numbers.  columns 3 & 5 are probably best as integers - I can round them.  A sample output, without formatting or headings is as follows.

```
Grid[Values[joinPMLs[group1CA, group2CA]] /. Missing["Unmatched"] -> "NA"]
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide minimal sample data (array) and column/row headings that represent the range of issues to be addressed.

Comment: you need to appy `NumberForm` to individual entries, ie `Grid[Map[NumberForm[#, 2] &, matrix, {2}]]` , not `Grid[NumberForm[matrix, 2]]]`  See also `TableForm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TableForm[
 {#[[1]], EngineeringForm[#[[2]], {3, 1}]} & /@ 
  Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[10^5]}, {10}],
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"Normal", "Engineering Form"}}
 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have an association, you can do it right away, if you have a list of lists, you need to convert it into an association and then perform formatting on individual columns, similar to what you would do in Excel, after which you can use [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html) or any other layout function:

```
data = {{1, 200000, 3, "string", Sin[z]/2}, 
        {100, 200, 1.5, 300, Sum[1/Cos[x], {x, a, b}]}};

adata = Inner[Rule,Table["C" <> ToString@i, {i, Length[data[[1]]]}], Transpose[data], Association];
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
(Query[All, {
            "C2" -> N /* (ScientificForm[#, 5] &),
            "C3" -> Round, 
            "C4" -> (If[IntegerQ@#, IntegerName[#], #] &),
            "C5" -> TraditionalForm
            }] @ adata) // Normal // Values // Grid
```

> [image]

Comment: My data originally was in a list of associations, but I went to values for my output to Excel.  For now, David's solution works well on my data.  I'll revisit your solution when I have more time to go back over my project and keep the data as a list of associations.  There may be other advantages I can gain by keeping it that way.